# Room database check for a condition before insert

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have to insert a value to table one in a hour for a specific id. I know it can be achieved by SQLite trigger but i read somewhere else that Room database currently doesn't support SQLite trigger function. 
How to achieve above task? I have included my data model here.

```
    @Entity(tableName = "device_table")
    public class Device {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String userId;
    private long time;


        public Device(String userId) {
             this.userId = userId;    

        }
      // and rest of the getter setter methods
    }
```

Comment: After giving answer I've understood that header of your post doesn't entirely corresponds with its body. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need SQLite trigger there (if update of your row doesn't depend on insert/delete another row|rows). You can divide your task to 2 subtasks:

1. How to create function, that updates row in Sqlite with some id.
2. How in Android invoke this function once in an hour.

**For first subtask** decision depends on how you want to update your data.
The simplest decision here - to use in your DAO interface method with @Insert annotation:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertDevice(device: Device)
```

You should put "updated" instance of your data class Device to this method.
"OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE" means that if row with this "id" exists, then row will be overridden, else - it will be added.

**For second subtask** you can use one of the mechanisms - Handler, Executor, Timer, AlarmManager, WorkManager (last works even if your app is inactive). There are many answers/examples on using them here on SO.